# Truncate String after ";" in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have some cells with long strings.
I want to truncate the cells within a column, so that only word(s) before a semicolon are maintained. For example, if I have a cell with the string `blue house; with green garden` I want to only maintain the words before the semicolon, so it would become `blue house`

Thank you!

Comment: Sound like a case for regular expression. https://regex101.com/ is a great place to start. Regarding `R` I'd recommend combining `substr` function with `regepxr` for `stop` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to delete the semi-colon and everything after it then this is a simple pattern that replaces such instances with the empty string: "".

```
blue <- c('blue house; with green garden')
gsub(";.*$", "", blue)
[1] "blue house"
```

The previously accepted answer uses a conditional/look-behind *and* a capture class, both useful concepts, but a bit complex for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

```
blue <- c('blue house; with green garden')
gsub('(;*?);.*', '\\1', blue)
[1] "blue house"
```

appears to work. When using the very nice [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), and you get something to work, remember to add another `\` to working examples when you use them in your terminal or RStudio.

Comment: @Nat: You only need to remember to use the extra backslash in the pattern argument, not the replacement argument.